# Where is the digital signature of a signed RPM stored?

Tags: digital-signature, rpm, yum, signed

While verifying digital signature of any file (rpm in this case), the signature file is separate from the file/message that it signs.

When we do, 
`$ rpm --checksig /path/to/mySignedPkg.rpm`

it has to verify the digital signature of mySignedPkg.rpm using the public RPM-GPG-KEYs of configured repos.

My question is, where is the digital signature of a signed RPM located?

If I extract the rpm using 
`$ rpm2cpio /path/to/mySignedPkg.rpm | cpio -idmv`

it does not show the digital signature file.

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to look at this further?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the Redhat security [blog](https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/3373211)

> The rpm file format is a binary format and broadly consists of 4
>   sections:
>
> - the legacy lead is a 96 byte header which contains "magic numbers" (used to identify file type) and other data;
> - an optional signature section;
> - a header which is an index containing information about the RPM package file; and
> - the cpio archive of the actual files to be written to the filesystem.

So it would appear the signature is part of the header which is why your unable to extract any sort of sig file directly.

[This](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-file-format-rpm-file-format.html) page on the RPM website gives a lot more specific detail into the header format - see the section on `Analyzing the Signature Area` for details.